# Entity Framework's rowversion convention-over-configuration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Is there some sort of convention-over-configuration on Entity Framework regarding the rowversion column? So I don't need to put any attribute on timestamp property

```
public class ProductId
{
    // [Key] // This is optional, EF automatically picks up 
    // ProductId as primary key
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductName { get; set; }

    // I want to remove Timestamp attribute, 
    // Fluent NHibernate CoC automatically picks up property with name of
    // Version as the rowversion property
    [Timestamp] 
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is but you will not like it. All data annotation attributes are handled by conventions so your example is the one which use it. There is no other convention dealing with row version.

Comment: I hope in the future Entity Framework, it will have something similar to Fluent NHibernate's conventions overrides across all classes